# How much energy does it take to flip a spin in a ferromagnet?

Tags: quantum-spin, ferromagnetism

Sorry the question is vague, I don't know what the name of the theory is that describes this so I don't know what to google. No need to explain anything just link me the wiki page pls.

Comment: Magnetic domains might be a start. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_domain. Also, read about Stern Gerlach experiments  there should be s set of links on each of these pages. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern–Gerlach_experiment

Answer (score 0):

The energy to flip a single spin is the interatomic exchange interaction $J$ times the number of magnetic neighbors. If you want a wikipedia article, this might be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model

Or this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superexchange

The best way to measure these energies directly used to be inelastic neutron diffraction. Now there is also inelastic x-ray scattering.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain how do you define Ising Hamiltonian on indistinguishable states? To me it looks possible only for distinguishable spins, but exchange interactions comes from indistinguishable principles... to me it seems possible to generalize it only with mean field. I mean assume for more than two spins,  psi (s) = sigma psi(S):=psi(sigma S) or psi(s)= sigma psi(S):=-psi(sigma S),  then E(psi) \neq E(sigma psi)).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/420784)